# KeyError: 'latitude'

Tags: csv, coordinates, streamlit, keyerror

I am trying to create a streamlit app to map coordinates from a csv with the ability to zoom to each point where a popup message appears with the attributes of that specific point. However I am getting this KeyError: latitude message even though I have no gaps in my latitude columns thus I am a bit perplexed how to solve this.

```
import folium
from folium import Map
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

def display_map(file):
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    m = Map(location=[data['latitude'].mean(), data['longitude'].mean()], zoom_start=13)
    for i, row in data.itterrows():
        folium.Marker(
        location=[row['latitude'], row['longitude']],
        popup=row['APPLICATION '],
        icon=folium.Icon(color='red')
    ).add_to(m)
   st.write(m)

def main():
    file = st.file_uploader("Upload a CSV File", type=["csv"])
    if file is not None:
         display_map(file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: fix `popup=row['APPLICATION']` and double check your spellings of the rows in the file and try running the code again.

Comment: Thought 1: One thing that tripped me up is the latitude and longitude columns need to be float64 type. Thought 2: is the error on the location parameter for your Map class or the location parameter for your Marker class?